# How to show dynamic video file in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get dynamic video into gridview. But i can't see the video. Video name exists in the database (within the column named 'Video') and i am giving path of the video in Item Template.

Check this out:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Video" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                <ItemTemplate>      <div style="text-align: left;">
                    <a href='<%#ResolveUrl("~/ProductVideos/" + Eval("Video")) %>' data-lightbox="" rel="lightbox" >
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl='<%# "~/ProductVideos/" + Eval("Video") + "width=50&height=50&mode=crop" %>' rel="lightbox" runat="server"  />
                        </a></div>
                        </ItemTemplate> 

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Product videos is the folder that contains the video. Now what may be the problem. Any help would be great.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will not run directly, you will have to use flash player for this and src of this flash player would be your file path. Flash player can be accessed through tag in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use HTML5, then video tag will be the easiest option:

`<video src='<%# "~/ProductVideos/" + Eval("Video").... %>'></video>`

More info here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/